# Как убрать ошибку на странице

Tags: php, wordpress

Как убрать на сайте вот такую ошибку

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function Редактировать_post_link() in /var/www/u0090067/data/www/infokaz.kz/wp-content/themes/the-newswire/content-page.php on line 10

Comment: Код файла wp-content/themes/the-newswire/content-page.php покажите что ли. Можно первый строк 20.

Comment: Какую функцию вы собираетесь использовать? `Редактировать_post_link` что-ли? Нет такой функции, есть [edit_post_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link). Тема какая-то корявая, сами пишите или чужую используете? Покажите код, как в комменте выше просили

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function Редактировать_post_link() in /var/www/u0090067/data/www/infokaz.kz/wp-content/themes/the-newswire/content-page.php on line 10

Comment: @АсельТабысова, все уже это поняли, нас интересует содержимое этого файла, отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте в него хотя бы 20 строчек из этого файла. Так же было бы полезно указать кто автор этой темы, если она получена откуда-то извне, то было бы неплохо привести ссылку на эту тему. Конкретно для данной ошибки должна помочь замена `Редактировать_post_link` на `edit_post_link`

Comment: Спасибо большое Ворон!! Я поняла и исправила после вашей подсказки))

Comment: @BOPOH Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий ответом.

Answer (score 1):

переключите вашу тему на WP или добавьте функцию `_post_link()`

Comment: куда добавить ?

Comment: так там не `_post_link` потеряли, а `Редактировать_post_link`. Не надо это никуда добавлять, `edit_post_link` уже есть

Comment: в таком случае я бы взглянул на `content-page.php on line 10`

Answer (score 1):

Сообщение говорит о том, в скрипте происходит обращение к функции _post_link() которая не была объявлена. Добавьте функцию, либо исключите её вызов.